# An adjective to replace "work-with-able"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I saw a YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/VzXHBPriTbI?t=370) and in this video, he says

> [...] and makes your hair more manageable and more **work-with-able,** if that's a word.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

Now I think it's perfectly fine to say something like that because, in daily conversations, you can make up words as much as you like. However, it's definitely *not* a word in a dictionary.

So my question is, what adjective is a good replacement for "work-with-able" in this context?

Comment: *Manageable* is fine. *Workable. Cooperative. Flexible. Compliable.* A million others. Also, why do you need it to be an adjective. Also also, what do you mean "it's definitely not a word"? It definitely looks like a word to me. What else is it?

Comment: I'm not sure what *work-with-able* is supposed to mean if it doesn't mean *manageable*.  If it does mean *manageable*, why would you need another word?

Comment: @RegDwigнt **First also,** I asked for adjective because I thought words that end with -able are adjectives (e.g. manageable), so if I'm to replace it, I have to use an adjective as well, am I wrong on that? **Second also,** it's not a word because it's not in the dictionary and I can't use "work-with-able" in an essay for example. I know a *made-up word* is still a word, but I'm looking for a replacement that's recognized by a dictionary.

Comment: @Juhasz Oh I see, so *manageable* itself can be a replacement.

Comment: @AmirAShabani yes, right now that slot in the sentence calls for an adjective. That is precisely my point. If you can't find a particular part of speech to shoehorn into a slot, rephrase the sentence such that you can use a different part of speech. If no adjective exists, use a noun. Or a verb.

Comment: As to words being or not being recognized by dictionaries, that's a dangerous approach to take. All dictionaries always lag behind the actual language, by definition. In order to find its way into a dictionary, the word needs to be created first. Note that "Reg" is not recognized by any dictionary, and neither is "Amir". Are these not words? Why are we calling ourselves things that are not words? How are people supposed to refer to you or me if our names are not words?

Comment: @RegDwigнt "[Amir](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amir)" is, in fact, in the dictionary, meaning *ruler.* But I see your point.

Comment: Isn't *manageable* on its own sufficient? It seems to me that adding *work-with-able* (or any synonym) is redundant.

Comment: @JasonBassford I believe it is 

Comment: Please check my edit and roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @aparente001 No, it is what I meant. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'd just given a mini-upvote for endorsing the best possible answer in this context, _manageable_, when I read further. I'm not going to go with 'any string possibly not containing blank spaces that has ever appeared in print, etc' even if the caveat 'transparent' is attached. There has to be some level of acceptance before a _non-word / candidate_ should be considered to have relocated into the lexis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply *workable*:

> Able to be worked, fashioned, or manipulated.
>   *‘more flour and salt can be added until they make a workable dough’*

(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workable))

The term "workable hair" is even used by hair cosmetics producers, e.g. [this product](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/631770653949694217/).

Comment: Okay, you found an example of someone using *workable* for hair.  But most people who work with their own or someone else's hair don't use *workable* for hair.  Working with bread dough or pie dough or cookie dough or whatever is completely different from working with hair.

Answer (score 1):

**Stylable**: Capable of being styled ([yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/stylable)).  **Style** (verb): form or arrange something in a particular way ([yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/style))